# Как с импортировать данные с одной таблицы в другую(немножко другую)? SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, sql-server-2008

дело в том что я всегда имел дело с простыми запросами, с созданием новых таблиц и подобного, на данный момент у меня есть задание, в чем заключается его суть :

---

Есть две таблицы:

**Таблица** с изменениями наименований улиц (**INPUT_CITY_NAME**)

```
ID Bigint (Primary key),
CITY_ID Bigint (City id),
CITY_NAME Nvarchar(255) (City name),
CITY_TYPE Int (City type FK),
dateStart Datetime (Valid from),
dateStop ID Datetime (Valid to)
```

---

**Таблица** типов улиц (INPUT_CITY_TYPE)

```
ID Bigint (Primaty key),
NAME Nvarchar(255) (Name of type),
GENITIVENAME Nvarchar(255) (Short name of type)
```

---

Сценарий:

Данные о населенных пунктах из мастер-системы импортируются в базу данных с эталонными данными.

Данные в мастер-системе хранятся в виде версий, причем поля DATESTART, DATESTOP показывают, в каком интервале дат значения действовала та или иная версия. Поле CITY_ID – одинаковое для всех строк, хранящих данные об одном и том же населенном пункте.

Как видно из таблицы INPUT_CITY_NAME, наименование населенного пункта может меняться, а может и не меняться, поле CITY_ID позволяет проследить изменение данных в мастер-системе

Проблема: в мастер-системе возможно дублирование данных (может быть несколько записей с разными CITY_ID, соответствующих одному и тому же населенному пункту)

---

Требуемый результат:

Новая таблица CITY, содержащая только одну строку для каждого населенного пункта (уникальная комбинация CITY_ID, CITY_NAME).
Разработать процедуру импорта в новую таблицу данных из мастер-системы с возможностью «склеивания» нескольких записей из мастер-системы в одну запись эталонного справочника. Вместе с данными о населенных пунктах сохранить также все значения CITY_ID исходной таблицы.
Опционально – обеспечить протоколирование изменений данных в целевой таблице эталонного справочника.

---

Вообщем если кратко то нужно создать таблицу CITY в которой данные не будут повторяться и они будут вытянуты с таблицы INPUT_CITY_NAME!
Кто чем может, помогите !
Прикреплю документ с базой https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0OiYKal8n_wMUV0akdxVF9YUWZTb2Z6c2o3cnRKZ2YteXZV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Отобрать последние по dateStart или dateStop записи для каждого CITY_ID, делов-то... надеюсь, что периоды действительности не пересекаются?

Comment: *и они будут вытянуты с таблицы INPUT_CITY_NAME* там нет данных о городах или датах. Она в описываемом процессе вообще не нужна.

Comment: я забыл прикрепить файл с примером, сейчас обновлю

Comment: *только одну строку для каждого населенного пункта (уникальная комбинация CITY_ID, CITY_NAME)* Эта фраза противоречива с учётом фразы *Поле CITY_ID – одинаковое для всех строк, хранящих данные об одном и том же населенном пункте*. Ничто не мешает согласно первой фразе иметь записи (1,"Зажопинск") и (1, "Крыжопль").

Comment: я добавил ссылку к файлу, может на примере будет более понятно

Comment: Файл не отвечает на вопрос и не устраняет противоречия в описании задачи. По большому счёту он вообще не нужен.

Comment: основа заключается в том что у меня может быть 5-6 одинаковых записей и отличаться у ни будет только   ID

Comment: привожу пример: это база для почты, предположим рейсом одесса - киев было заказано 30 единиц товара в одно и тоже время, так вот в этом   INPUT_CITY_NAME будет целых 30 одинаковых записей, а мне нужна одна, на сколько я правильно понял это задание

Comment: последний Ваш комментарий вообще описывает совершенно иной процесс и совершенно иную задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально:

```
WITh cte AS (SELECT id, city_id, city_name, city_type, dateStart, dateStop, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY dateStart DESC) rn
             FROM input_city_name)
INSERT INTO new_input_city_name (id, city_id, city_name, city_type, dateStart, dateStop)
SELECT id, city_id, city_name, city_type, dateStart, dateStop
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: попробую, спасибо)

Comment: а вы не могли бы при возможности немножко объяснить как работает ваш код? я не со всем знаком просто, если не затруднит !

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya Уточните, что именно вызывает сложности. [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175972%28v%3dsql.105%29), [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186734%28v%3dsql.105%29), [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189461%28v%3dsql.105%29).

Comment: оно все в совокупности вызывает сложность, но я думаю что скоро все пойму, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Идея - нумеруем записи отдельно для каждого `city_id` в порядке уменьшения `dateStart`, после чего оставляем только записи с номером 1 (т.е. для каждого `city_id` оставляем только одну запись, у которой `dateStart` самый большой).

Comment: добрый день! не могли бы вы помочь мне еще разочек?

Comment: Вместе с данными о населенных пунктах нужно было сохранить также все значения CITY_ID исходной таблицы.

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya Не понял фразы. В выходном наборе поле `city_id` присутствует.